# Wanted to back up blockchain to save space, now I cannot open bitcoin QT?

Tags: blockchain

I wanted to back up the blockchain on my hard drive as it took around 50 GB on my laptop. I did so and deleted all the `blk000.dat` and the `rev000.dat` from (`~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/`) which are saved on my hard drive. Apparently this was a stupid mistake as I cannot open Bitcoin QT anymore. I therefore re-transfered everything back to the same folder. But nothing happens, and Bitcoin Core does not open.

After looking around, many are mentioning a `bootstrap.dat` file which correspond to the block chain. I cannot seem to find this file anywhere on my laptop.

Any clues? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Delete your `chainstate` and `blocks` folder and start Bitcoin-Qt again. It will then re-sync your blockchain.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about the bootstrap file. That's old and obsolete information.

Did you turn off bitcoin-qt every time before you copied or deleted files?

You may need to just let bitcoin-qt re-download the whole blockchain. Make sure you backup your wallet (wallet.dat).